# UDFArgumentTypeException Expected: Exactly one argument expected - Sum() issue

Tags: sql, join, hive, aggregate-functions, hiveql

I am running this query in HIVE 0.12

```
select X.PERS_KEY, Y.*, sum(Y.PAID_AMT, Y.DEDUCT_AMT) AS CHRG_AMT, sum(Y.PAID_AMT, Y.DEDUCT_AMT, Y.CHRG_VAL) AS CHRG_AMT2
from MEMBERS X 
LEFT JOIN
    (select PERS_KEY, CLM_KEY, DIAG_CD, PAID_AMT, DEDUCT_AMT, CHRG_VAL from clm_table where DIAG_CD < 10) Y
ON X.PERS_KEY=Y.PERS_KEY
```

I'm sure the issue is with the sum() functions in the outer query, but I'm not sure why it is an issue. Why can't we simply take some variables in a row and create a new variable that is the sum of them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`sum` function takes exactly one argument. You should use `Y.PAID_AMT + Y.DEDUCT_AMT` if you need to sum up those values.